# How do I change the defined brush in a Photoshop brush preset?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

Most brush presets have a defined brush but I forget the command to release the defined brush and choose my own brush temporarily.

For instance, if I choose a brush preset that has a regular brush defined and I want to use the mixer brush instead, what commands release the defined regular brush?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for *Photoshop* and may or may not fit with (Photoshop) *Lightroom*. The application specifics were unclear when this answer was posted.

---

Just change some of the brush settings or dynamics. I don't think there's anything to "release" unless you see a little lock icon next to a dynamic.. click that to unlock the dynamic associated with the lock.

Not really certain what you're asking. The default presets are merely settings, once you change a setting, that preset is no longer active. If you want to save a preset with your new settings, then save a new preset.

And the Brush Tool and Mixer Brush tool are separate *tools* not merely setting variations.

Comment: Thank you for that bit of info Scott. There is a key command option that allows release of the brush and if I find it again, I will post. Your info is a good work around in the mean time.

Comment: I *honestly* don't know what you mean by "release of brush". I've used Photoshop for more than 30 years and have never heard that term. And Photoshop has no command for "release brush" anywhere which I am aware of.

Comment: Hi Scott, In a preset, many times, there are brushes that are defined within the preset. Note the red circles on the brush presets in Photoshop  https://lightroom.adobe.com/shares/d695cefb84bf4da7a67d16f9a4d75a79

There is a command to allow you to release that preset brush: normal or mixer brush and choose any other brush you want. 

Do I make any sense?

Comment: That would appear to be a **Lightroom** screenshot.. not Photoshop. I know it's technically titled "Photoshop Lightroom" but it is a different application than the flagship Photoshop. When most read "Photoshop" they *are not* thinking of Lightroom. Much the same way I had *no clue* you were referring to Lightroom in your question. I am not a Lightroom user. (it's kind of pointless if you use the flagship product).

Comment: Nope, I am referring to Photoshop. Lightroom does not have many brush options. The gallery is a Lightroom gallery but the screenshot is Photoshop. I use them both simultaneously.

Comment: Well I honestly have no clue then.. those panels aren't like my panels.. [**SEE HERE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqwV7.png). I thought maybe you were looking at the Tool Presets.. but nope no such right-side icons there either. I am not seeing a single panel in Photoshop CC2018/Mac with those icons on the right side.

Comment: .. see now you've got me wondering *why* the panels in your screenshot are different than what I'm seeing. Maybe a Mac/Windows thing?

Comment: Hi Scott, I have a Mac and am working on PHOTOSHOP CC 2018. When I look at what you posted, it seems like an older version Photoshop but perhaps it is just a Mac. vs PC thing or I have some odd setting in my preferences.  Here is a screen shot of my whole working interface with only Photoshop open. I am using the painting  workspace.

Comment: Might be the difference in OS versions. At the time I was booted to 10.10.5 not 10.13. It's not common for entire feature sets to be disabled due to the OS version though. The UI, sure, but not features.